# Is here a way to solve this error message; Web3 is not defined?

Tags: javascript, web3js

js code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const http = require('http')
const web3_utils = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')
const moment = require('moment-timezone')
const numeral = require('numeral')
const _ = require('lodash')
const axios = require('axios')

// SERVER CONFIG
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ 
PORT }`))

// WEB3 CONFIG
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL) '''
```

In terminal after npm run start, the output is:
node index.js

```
/home/trosilez/price-bot/index.js:18
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL)
         ^

ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/trosilez/price-bot/index.js:18:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Web3 is not defined because you did not include the variable "Web3" when importing your dependencies.

Rename web3_utils to Web3. It should look this.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get around this I had to install an old version of web3

$ npm i web3@0.20.6